# WhatsApp does not download images during call

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, media-files

During a WhatsApp call, if I receive a media element from a WhatsApp contact (does not necessarily has to be the person whom I am talking with), the loading icon rotates, but the download of the element never starts.

First I thought it is due to my internet connection, but regardless of my speed, it is the same for LTE+ or WLAN connections.

Is that intentional? How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: This happens only on Android phones. On iPhones, this does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, in my case on Galaxy S7 running Android version 8.0. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: Hi. Apparently this is a bug that they do not intend to solve. However, I found a workaround. Tap on X to stop downloading, and tap on the picture again to download it.

Comment: @www you should make your comment as an answer and OP to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug that still exists. However, I found a workaround. Tap on X to stop downloading the media, and tap again to download it.